# What is the content of mod_evasive Log File

Tags: drivers, updates, xubuntu, apache2, security

After the configuration of the ***mod_evasive***. I found a log file there with the name of

> dos-172.15.156.125

and the content was in the file is

> 15243

Could you please help me out what is this no. ***15243***?

Answer (score 3):

After inspect the source files on https://github.com/jzdziarski/mod_evasive

The number inside the log file is the Process ID returned by the function `getpid()` which

> returns the process ID (PID) of the calling process.  (This is often
>   used by routines that generate unique temporary filenames.)

check this page for more details https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html